# Add class to element within pug iteration

Tags: iteration, pug

I require some help in adding a class to this PUG iteration, to any one li item element of choice. Not sure if I am approaching this incorrectly.

```
each val, index in ['one', 'two', 'three']
    li
        a(href='#')= val
```

**Required Output**

```
<ul>
    <li class="foo"><a href="#">One</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Two</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Three</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that with a ternary operator in the attribute list of your `li` element:

```
each val, index in ['one', 'two', 'three']
    li(class= (index === 0 ? "foo" : undefined))
        a(href='#')= val
```

If the problem situation permits, however, I'd suggest using CSS pseudo-classes (such as `:first-child`) to achieve this in a cleaner way :)

Comment: Unfortunately did not work and using the pseudo-class would not be an option as there could be a possibility of adding the class to other items. Just updated the ticket to reflect this.

Comment: I have it working in [this CodePen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/pRaRyz) (following your specification as closely as possible). Is there something I missed?

Comment: My bad, had the comma after val missing. Done Thanks :)